# Linear Regression in R for Date and some dependant output

Tags: r, datetime, regression, linear-regression

Actually I need to calculate the parameters theta0 and theta1 using linear regression. 
My data frame (data.1) consists of two columns, first one is a date-time and the second one is a result which is dependent on this date.
Like this:

```
        data.1[[1]]  data.1[[2]]
2004-07-08 14:30:00        12.41
```

Now, I have this code for which iterates over a number of times to calculate the parameter `theta0`, `theta1`

```
x=as.vector(data.1[[1]])
y=as.vector(data.1[[2]])

plot(x,y)

theta0=10
theta1=10
alpha=0.0001
initialJ=100000
learningIterations=200000

J=function(x,y,theta0,theta1){
m=length(x)
sum=0
for(i in 1:m){
  sum=sum+((theta0+theta1*x[i]-y[i])^2)
}
sum=sum/(2*m)
return(sum)
}

updateTheta=function(x,y,theta0,theta1){
sum0=0
sum1=0
m=length(x)
for(i in 1:m){
   sum0=sum0+(theta0+theta1*x[i]-y[i])
   sum1=sum1+((theta0+theta1*x[i]-y[i])*x[i])
 }
sum0=sum0/m
sum1=sum1/m
theta0=theta0-(alpha*sum0)
theta1=theta1-(alpha*sum1)
 return(c(theta0,theta1))
}    

for(i in 1:learningIterations){
thetas=updateTheta(x,y,theta0,theta1)
tempSoln=0
tempSoln=J(x,y,theta0,theta1)
if(tempSoln<initialJ){
  initialJ=tempSoln
}
if(tempSoln>initialJ){
   break
 }
theta0=thetas[1]
theta1=thetas[2]
#print(thetas)
#print(initialJ)
plot(x,y)
lines(x,(theta0+theta1*x), col="red")
  }
  lines(x,(theta0+theta1*x), col="green")
```

Now I want to calculate theta0 and theta1 using the following scenarios:

1. `y=data.1[[2]]` and `x=dates` which are similar irrespective of the year
2. `y=data.1[[2]]` and `x=months` which are similar irrespective of the year

Please suggest..

Comment: Linear regression in `R` is implemented through the `lm` function. See `?lm` for details.

Comment: @Mohit if my answer has helped you, please mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Nicola said, you need to use the [`lm` function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/lm.html) for linear regression in `R`.
If you'd like to learn more about `linear regression` check out [this](http://www.statmethods.net/stats/regression.html) or follow [this tutorial](http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/simple-linear-regression)

First you would have to determine your formula. You want to calculate `Theta0` and `Theta1` using `data.1[[2]]` and `dates`/`months`.

Your first formula would be something along the lines of:

```
formula <- Theta0 ~ data.1[[2]] + dates
```

Then you would create the `linear model`

```
variablename <- lm(formula, dataset)
```

After this you can use the output for various calculations.
For example you can calculate anova, or just print the summary:

```
anova(variablename)
summary(variablename)
```

---

**Sidenote:**.
I noticed your assigning variables by using `=`. This is not recommended parenthesis. For more information check out [Google's R Style Guide](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Rguide.xml)
In `R` it would be preferred to use `<-` to assign variables.
Taking the first bit of your code, it would become:

```
x <- as.vector(data.1[[1]])
y <- as.vector(data.1[[2]])

plot(x,y)

theta0 <- 10
theta1 <- 10
alpha <- 0.0001
initialJ <- 100000
learningIterations <- 200000
```

Comment: `=` assignment is not "wrong" is a style choice and may even be part of the style guide where Mohit works.